# Failed low quality posts review audit but couldn't go back to look at the post

Tags: support, review-audits

I failed a low quality post review audit for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250531/adding-tinycon-library-to-woocommerce-show-products-in-cart-count-on-the-favic/28250532#28250532), and got the "hey, pay attention!" message, saying that post had been deleted for being "abusive or spam". It hadn't made that impression on me (it was a block of PHP code offering a solution and paragraph of explanation), but I wanted to check it over to see what it was that I had missed so I wouldn't make the same mistake again. However the offending answer was not displayed underneath the audit failed message, and when I clicked back in my browser the answer was gone. Clicking the link to it got a 404 because it has been deleted.

Now most likely I was wrong, but I still would have liked to be able to see why, otherwise the potential learning experience of the audit seems to be wasted. Can I do that?

Comment: The post was indeed deleted as spam, but I am not convinced it actually deserved to be. The post *was* poorly worded, with words like *I just came across with a solution for implementing TinyCon with WooCommerce. I use this super-easy, leightweight library to display cart quantity on the favicon.* which does come over as rather spammy. The library used is Open Source and hosted on GitHub with no obvious connection to the poster.

Comment: It could be the user is a repeat offender however and this not the only post promoting a library. [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250646) is a link-only post to an external blog. Not directly spam, but not helpful either.

Comment: ["Allow all reviewers to see deleted posts they reviewed"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, thanks. Are the lists of audit posts manually curated, or are they automatically generated by the system? It doesn't seem right to have borderline cases, or cases where the correct decision depends on knowing the poster's history in the audits.

Comment: @samgak: they are automated and there is always the possibility a bad audit slips in. This was such a bad audit, I think. Another moderator reinstated, then re-deleted the post to clear the spam marker, it won't be used now for future audits.

Comment: Unless blatant, spam posts are often difficult to recognize in isolation. What makes them spam can be a pattern of repetitive posts. There is a proposal to not use them as audits: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/262723.