# Review low quality post failure, should I have skipped it?

Tags: support, review-queues

I came accros [this question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285039/failed-low-quality-posts-review-audit-but-couldnt-go-back-to-look-at-the-post) searching about this and I'm still in doubt.

I failed a review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7029072).

I had a doubt about it, but I felt it was giving an answer without only promoting a software (some background explanation on the root causes).

The question on itself sounds off topic, but is 11 month old without any answer and was not downvoted.

Should I have skipped the review in doubt ?

I did saw some question around this topic but I'm still wondering if I should just left that behind as a 50/50 error between me and the system or if I should have skipped it.

If I missed an existing one on this topic thanks in advance for the link and I'll delete this question.

Addition on why I reviewed it "Looks Ok":
I didn't take care of the OS tags nor the android point in the OP question as it is about a FAT formatted card, the answer is not strictly correct but still true.

The type of files (photo versus audio) is of no interest in the process of recovering files (the process would be the same).

I clearly agree the question is Off topic and the answer not great, but I really fail (and can't reread it to) to understand why it should be deleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At first glance, it *looks* like it's giving an answer, sympathizing with the OP and then recommending a helpful piece of software. That's the problem with a wall-of-text answer; sometimes it's hard to tell exactly *what* it's saying, and if any of it is useful.

At a closer glance, about the only informative piece in the answer is this, which is pretty useless since the OP mentions Android and Linux, not Windows.

> The file content still exists on the hard disk, Windows simply marks the hard drive and notify the file system that the space the file formerly occupy is free and can be re-usable.

Everything after that is about some piece of software that only seems to exist on sites like cnet and softonic, and about how great it is for recovering photos. The OP didn't mention photos, but did mention "image file" and "disk image", which is probably why the spammer targeted the post.

Plus, if you google the first few sentences of the "answer", you'll get hits for similar posts on other sites. One was a thread where people were sharing their preferred photo editors, and then out of the blue, this same answer.

I wouldn't say you should've skipped it... definitely a candidate for deletion.

---

Here's the original answer, for those who can no longer view it:

[image]

Comment: Ok, sadly I felt in the same problem as the other question I linked, I can't have another look at the answer to get where I failed (nor to google it). I didn't take care of the OS tags as the question is about a FAT formatted card, the answer is not strictly correct but still true. The type of files is of no interest in the process of recovering files (the process would be the same). I clearly agree the question is Off topic and the answer not so great, but I really fail (and can't reread it) to understand. I'll update my question with this comment as it seems it can enlight it.

Comment: Thanks Grant, clearly not an answer to OP question in audio recovery, just on file recovery which was not the question goal in fact. (now wondering if my question should be deleted or not ;))

Comment: Is the software that is being 'promoted' Audacity?  FWIW, that is free software that is commonly used by developers who work with audio streams.  My opinion is that the OP had a legitimate question.  I probably would have also clicked __Looks OK__.

Comment: @GrantWinney Ah, I understand now.

Comment: Are you sure you want to give spam a second life, now embedded in meta?